# Using RecursiveDirectoryIterator on a remote server

Tags: php, phpseclib

### I have a script that works on a stand alone VPS (here is a snippet

```
//Iteration in Directory 
$path = realpath('registry');
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$path_live = array();


foreach($objects as $name => $object)
{
if (is_file($name))
    $path_live[] = $name;
}


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to get this to work between two VPSs?

I have installed phpseclib  and can login to remote VPS, but I'm not sure how to get this to work.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
//Iteration in Directory 
$path = realpath('registry');
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$path_live = array();


foreach($objects as $name => $object)
{
if (is_file($name))
    $path_live[] = $name;
}

//Iteration in Directory 
$path2 = realpath('...');
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path2), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
$path_live = array();


foreach($objects as $name => $object)
{
if (is_file($name))
    $path_live[] = $name;
}
```

Works for me. If there's something specific you're trying to do with the two VPS's you're going to have to elaborate.